# Is it known that $NEXP = \Sigma_2 \implies NEXP = MA$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, conditional-results

Is it known whether the implication $\mathsf{NEXP} = \Sigma_2 \implies \mathsf{NEXP} = \mathsf{MA}$ holds?

(The question is inspired by well-known $\mathsf{NEXP} \subseteq \mathsf{P/poly} \Leftrightarrow \mathsf{NEXP} = \mathsf{MA}$.)

Comment: Crosspost from [cs.se](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11973) where it did not get an answer.

Comment: Interesting question!  All I can say is that *I* don't know of any result of this kind, nor do I know of any existing techniques that seem up to it.  Granted, the hypothesis is extremely strong, but in some sense a collapse to Sigma_2 seems "still too high above MA's head" for MA to reach up and grab it.

Comment: Answered on CS.SE: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11973/755